# I can't open nautilus after executing rm -rf ~/.ddd/

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, helpfile

I tried to install ddd from my schools site and it gave me this command to remove installed version of ddd:

```
rm -rf ~/.ddd/
```

It wouldn't execute so i tried with `sudo` and it worked, but after that i couldn't open nautilus. When i tried to start it from the terminal it displayed this:

```
Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created: /home/sensej/.config/nautilus
```

Output of    `ls -ld ~/.config`    is:

```
ls: cannot access '~/.config':No such file or directory
```

Output of `sudo ls -ld ~/.config` :

```
ls: cannot access '/home/sensej/.config': No such file or directory
```

And here is the output of `history`

```
 1  sudo apt-get install gcc
    2  sudo apt-get install ddd
    3  ddd
    4  gcc
    5  ddd
    6  sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
    7  sudo apt-get intall gcc-multilib
    8  sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
    9  cd Downloads
   10  ls
   11  sudo cp asm.lang /usr/ sudo cp asm.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
   12  ls /usr/share/mime/packages/Overrides.xml
   13  udo cp Overrides.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/
   14  sudo cp Overrides.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/
   15  sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
   16  ls
   17  mkdir Asembler
   18  cd Asembler
   19  gedit &
   20  ls
   21  gcc -m32 -g -o zbir_n_brojeva zbir_n_brojeva.S
   22  ./zbir_n_brojeva.S
   23  ddd zbir_n_brojeva &
   24  rm -rf ~/ .ddd/
   25  sudo rm -rf ~/ .ddd/
   26  sudo apt-get install ddd
   27  sudo apt-get purge nautilus
   28  sudo apt-get install nutilus
   29  nautilus --check
   30  sudo apt install nautilu
   31  sudo apt install nautilus
   32  nutilus --check
   33  clear
   34  nautilus --check
   35  sudo apt-get intall --reinstall nautilu-data
   36  sudo apt-get intall --reinstall nautilus-data
   37  sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
   38  nautilus
   39  ddd
   40  nautilus
   41  sudo chown sensej:sensej ~/.config
   42  mkdir /home/sensej/.config
   43  sudo mkdir /home/sensej/.config
   44  nautilus
   45  cd .
   46  hitory
   47  history
   48  ls -l ~/.config
   49  ls -l ~/ .config
   50  ls -ld ~./config
   51  history
   52  sudo ls -ld ~/ .config
   53  history
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls -ld ~/.config` terminal command.

Comment: But I suspect you ran something else with sudo.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just typed sudo in front of this command, nothing else was changed.

Comment: You can run `history` and see what you really ran.

Comment: I suspect something like `sudo nautilus`, etc.

Comment: And also please add output of `ls -l ~/.config`

Comment: the datadir of nautilus available on `~/.config/nautilus` path, did you try just type `nautilus` on your terminal?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri yes and it gave me some criticals and some warinings

Comment: @Pilot6 I typed sudo rm -rf ~/ .ddd/ . And ls -l ~/ .config gives me no such file or directiry. and please be patient with me i am noob about this stuff

Comment: what the commands you type before execute `rm -rf ~/.ddd/` command with run `history` and please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1122464/edit) your question with that output?

Comment: Don't post any "code". Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and post output I asked for.

Comment: Please don't retype outputs. You make errors there. Copy text directly from the terminal.

Comment: Run it with sudo now `sudo ls -ld ~/.config`.

Comment: Can you see the difference between  `~/.config` and `~./config`?

Comment: @Pilot6 yeah i see it, i am jut a bit annoyed so i miss some things

Comment: `sudo mkdir /home/sensej/.config` this was wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 that didn't do anything it was happening before that

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm sorry i'm a bit slow, i edited the real output of command you asked for now

Comment: see the answer. You deleted all your files

Comment: can you check your home directory with type `ll` on your terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran a completely wrong command

```
rm -rf ~/ .ddd/
```

It removed your home directory `~/`.

The correct command was

```
rm -r ~/.ddd/
```

You added a space there. You seem to be a bit careless with adding spaces.

Since your home directory is gone, I suggest re-installing the system.

Beware that you lost all your files. Be careful in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: I agree with your diagnosis - but reinstalling the system seems like overkill. Couldn't the OP just create a new home directory and restore their personal files from backup for example?

Comment: @steeldriver All configs are lost. That`s the problem. It will be easier to re-install for a newbie.

Comment: @steeldriver How can you see successful creating and restoring with this kind of CLI skills?

Comment: The vast majority of configs will be recreated when the relevant programs are executed for the first time. The rest could be copied from `/etc/skel`. I agree that reinstalling is needlessly extreme here.